# Start glassfish in LINUX server remotely

Tags: shell-script, php

I want to start glassfish on a server running LINUX, the problem is that my service provider does not grant access to ssh connections nor any other helpful tool to run `asadmin start-domain` I have tried using php to start glassfish and does not work (it does not show any error message either I suppose that php protects the execution of those files but it was worth to gave it a shot) neither cron works, I also try creating a shell script and run it using php but nothing, I already ran out of ideas to try to start the glassfish service, if you have any idea I would appreciate.

P.D: Contacting my service provider is not an idea, it does not work hehehe

not sure if the question should be posted here or in SuperUser, if you consider it is more appropriate to move it please go ahead

Comment: That's difficult without knowing how the service provider has set up that system. What exactly did you try in PHP? Who is the service provider? This question may work better on a user forum for that service provider, because the answer may well rely on the details of what they do and don't allow.

Comment: Yes, I am quite aware that the service provider may be my best option to solve this problem, but they took weeks (note the last s in weeks) to reply, the SP is name.com, the functions I used in PHP are exec and shell_exec

Comment: I'm suggesting asking other users of that SP, if you can find a place where these users gather. Without even knowing what provider this is, let alone what restrictions they might have implemented, we can only offer a shot in the dark.